# Integral inequality with Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f(a)=0$ and so that $f'$ is continuous. Show that
$$\int_a^b |{f(x)f'(x)}|\:\mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{b-a}{2} \int_a^b f'(x)^2\: \mathrm{d}x.$$

I received a hint for examining the function $G(x):=\int_a^x |f'(t)|\:\mathrm{d}t$ but haven't really gotten anywhere with it. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any relation between $G(x)$ and $|f(x)|$?

Comment: Only things I know about $G(x)$ is that $G(a)=0=f(a)$ and $G' = |f'|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe too long for a comment, did you tried Holder's inequality ?
$$\int_a^b|f(x)f'(x)|\mathrm{d}x \le \left( \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{a}^{b}|f'(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\tag{1}$$
Now write $$f(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)\mathrm{d}t \tag{1}$$
Now from (2) we may write 
$$|f(x)| \le \int_a^x|f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t \le (x-a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_a^x |f'(t)|^2 \mathrm{d}t \right)^{1/2}$$
Then we have 
$$\int_a^b|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x \le \int_a^b(x-a)\int_a^x|f'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x \le \int_a^b |f'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t\int_a^b(x-a)\mathrm{d}x$$
It's a few steps from here i guess

Comment: We aren't allowed to use Holder's inequality yet. Should have said that, sorry about it.

Comment: Well this is mere Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality or Cauchy–Schwarz if you like, you'd like to try or should i add more ?

Comment: The absolute values confuse me a bit. Could you add more please?

Comment: Why does the 2nd inequality in the third line hold?

Comment: @Shuster That's cauchy-schwarz again, write $$\begin{align}\int_a^x|f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t=\int_a^x|1 \cdot f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t & \le\left (\int_a^x|1|^2\mathrm{d}t \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_a^x |f'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2} \\ &\le(x-a)^{1/2}\left(\int_a^x |f'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}\end{align}$$

Comment: I am not sure if we are getting the $\frac{b-a}{2}$ constant from this. It seems like we get $\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2}}$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @r9m no i think you're right, i never calculated the whole thing, the bound i'm getting now is $\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2}}$ not the desired one, i wonder what's wrong here

Comment: I think in the 4th line we have $\int_a^b (x-a)\int_a^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt \,dx = \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}\int_a^b |f'(t)|^2\,dt \color{red}{-} (\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b (x-a)^2|f'(x)|^2\,dx)$. Equality occurs in OP's inequality when $f(x) = \lambda(x-a)$. By ignoring the bracketed term additionally we are loosing sharpness here.

Comment: From eqn $(2)$, $|f(x)| \le \int_a^x |f'(t)|\,dt = G(x)$ multiplying $G'(x) = |f'(x)|$ on both sides and integrating over $[a,b]$ seems to be fixing it.

Comment: Right, this does the trick, thank you.