# How do I prove $\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \int_a^b |f'(x)|^2 dx$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be $C^1[a,b]$ continuously differentiable) with $f(a)=0$. **[This may be generalized to $f(b)=0$ or $f(a)f(b)=0$]**

I want to show

> $$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\ \mathrm{d}x\ \leq\ \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \int_a^b
>  |f'(x)|^2\ \mathrm{d}x.$$

---

Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous so it is integrable.  And since $f'$ is continuous so it is integrable.  So, L.H.S and R.H.S are well defined.

My first trial was the usage of integration by parts, but since I am dealing with $|\cdot |$, the absolute value of a function, it seems it is not a good direction.

Comment: $f(x)=\int_a^{x}f'(t)dt$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646679/integral-inequality-with-cauchy-schwarz-inequality?noredirect=1 or this https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h546384p3162147

Comment: @Sumanta, WOW Thanks! It was Wirtinger's inequality! The second link really helps me a lot

Comment: @phy_math I guess you are going through this proof: geodesic is locally(in a chart) length minimizing curve among all smooth curves in the same chart having same endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Sumanta comments, Based on the second link, I just make up a solution.

The first link [Integral inequality with Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646679/integral-inequality-with-cauchy-schwarz-inequality?noredirect=1), use Holder inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with proper and do integral with proper assumption, and the second link use only Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Frankly speaking, it is nothing but a re-arranging(=copy paste) the proof in  the second link

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \int_a^x f'(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$.  Now from Cauchy-Schwartz   one have
\begin{align}
  \left( \int_a^x |f'(t)|\ \mathrm{d}t \right)^2
  \leq \left( \int_a^x |f'(t) |^2\ \mathrm{d}t \right) \left(\int_a^x 1^2\ \mathrm{d}t \right)  
\end{align}
Since $\displaystyle f(x)^2 =  \left( \int_a^x f'(t)\ \mathrm{d}t \right)^2  \leq  \left( \int_a^x |f'(t)|\ \mathrm{d}t \right)^2$  we have
\begin{align}
  &f^2 (x) = \left( \int_a^x f'(t)\ \mathrm{d}t \right)^2
  \leq \left( \int_a^b |f'(t)|^2\ \mathrm{d}t \right) (x-a)   \\
  &\quad \implies \quad 
  \int_a^b f(x)^2\ \mathrm{d}x \leq \left(\int_a^b |f'(t)|^2\ \mathrm{d}t \right) \int_a^b (t-a)\ \mathrm{d}t   \\
  & \quad \implies \quad 
  \int_a^b |f(t)|^2\ \mathrm{d}t \leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \left( \int_a^b |f'(t) |^2\ \mathrm{d}t \right)  
\end{align}
*This inequality is called "Wirtinger's inequality."*